# Adding context menu to Windows Explorer to run BAT files

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there any way to add a new entry to windows explorer context menu that could run a BAT file/command with the selected file as argument.

Specifically, I need to do:

```
pscp -pw password E:\File.txt myname@machine.univ.edu:/home/myname/Files/
```

on right clicking the file and selecting the menu item "Copy to server" in windows explorer.

Comment: which language, framework and version of windows do you want to do this in?

Comment: I'm voting -1, because this question is vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need shell extension. CHeck out this for complete guide: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguideindex.aspx

And dont forget "**Do not write in-process shell extensions in managed code**". Details here:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061218-01/?p=28693

Answer (score 0):

Add some lines to the registry (untested):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell\pscp]
@="Copy To Server"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell\pscp\command]
@="%SystemRoot%\\system32\\cmd.exe /c \"P:\\ath\\to\\batch.cmd" \"%1\" %*"
```

Replace P:\ath\to\batch.cmd with your batch file, or try directly (untested):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell\pscp\command]
@="W:\\here\\it\\is\\pscp.exe -pw password \"%1\" myname@machine.univ.edu:/home/myname/Files/"
```