# How to add batch script to context menu of multiple computers

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry, contextmenu

I've been trying to setup a batch script that can be run from the context menu inside a folder. The purpose of the batch script is to populate the folder with a predetermined folder structure.

This will need to be replicated on multiple computers(Windows 7-10), so my idea was to have a network share with two batch files and one .reg file. One of the batch files labeled "install.cmd" would copy the other batch file labeled "Subfolders.cmd" to a folder on the C drive, and run the .reg file to install a shortcut on the context menu to the "Subfolders.cmd" batch file.

I have created the "Subfolders.cmd" batch file and it works, but it has to be run from inside the folder I want the folder structure setup in. I would appreciate any help on how to create the "install.cmd" batch script that would create a folder on the C drive, copy the "Subfolders.cmd" script into it, and run the .reg file to create the item in the context menu that would allow the "Subfolders.cmd" batch script to be run in selected folder.

I'd appreciate any examples and/or suggestions of more efficient ways of doing this. Thanks!

Update: As requested, I have posted the code that generates the subfolders inside an opened folder. It's pretty simple.

```
md "Folder1" "Folder1/Sub1A" "Folder1/Sub1B" "Folder2" "Folder2/Sub2A" "Folder2/Sub2B"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding context menu to Windows Explorer to run BAT files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162415/adding-context-menu-to-windows-explorer-to-run-bat-files)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for all this copying.

```
"\\computername\sharename\folder\file.bat"
```

Will run a batch file stored on another computer.

Ditto the reg command

```
regedit /s "\\computername\sharename\folder\file.reg"
```

You can do the above with the older mapped drives as well as UNC.

You need to show your second script so we can see why it NEEDS to be in the folder.

**EDIT**

You need to specify full paths.

To get the starting folder use `%V` in the registry command. So (and lets get rid of the reg file) (add your bat instead of echo)

```
reg add "HKCR\Directory\Background\Shell\Test Command\command" /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "cmd /k echo ""%V"""
```

In your batch use `%1` to get the starting folder, and tilde (`%~1`) to remove quotes (see `call /?` for documentation). (remember create folders from the lowest level as higer levels get made automatically).

```
md "%~1\folder1\folder2"
```

Comment: Bill, I've updated my original post with the code as you requested. I suppose keeping the batch file on the network share has advantages, including one central location to update as necessary. Thanks for the idea! Don't know why I didn't think of that. I still need to run the batch file inside the folder, and the answers that I found, in regards to adding a batch file to the context menu, didn't seem to help me much, as they didn't appear to run the batch file inside the opened folder.

Comment: You can see a working example built in to windows with open command prompt background menu item.

Comment: I'm unable to get this to work. When you say I need to replace echo with my bat are you intending it to read "cmd /k md "%~1\Folder1\Folder2" ""%V""" or "cmd /k \\network address\share folder\file.bat ""%V""" ? I've tried both without success.